# Passing delegate parameter to MethodInfo.Invoke

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I have a window with multiple radio buttons : first group Sorting Algorithms and second directions (Ascending, Descending).

Every Sorting Method that I have contains :

```
 public delegate bool ComparatorDelegate(int a, int b);
 public static int[] sort(int[] array, ComparatorDelegate comparator){...}
```

and I mention that I need to keep this signatures (specially passing a delegate as a parameter).

Now the problem is , I have two methods 
First one retrieves the selected algorithm

```
private Type getSelectedSortingMethod()
    {
        if (radioButtonBubbleSort.Checked)
        {
            return typeof(BubbleSort);
        }
        else if (radioButtonHeapSort.Checked)
        {
             return typeof(HeapSort);
        }
        else if (radioButtonQuickSort.Checked)
        {
             return typeof(QuickSort);
        }
        else
        {
             return typeof(SelectionSort);
        }
    }
```

and the second one retrieves the direction :

```
   private Func<int, int, bool> getSelectedDirection()
    {
        Func<int, int, bool> selectedDirectionComparator = null;
        if (radioButtonAscending.Checked)
        {
            selectedDirectionComparator = ComparatorUtil.Ascending;
        }
        else if (radioButtonDescending.Checked)
        {
            selectedDirectionComparator = ComparatorUtil.Descending;
        }
        return selectedDirectionComparator;
    }
```

`Question : How can I invoke the sort method with a delegate parameter , because passing Func throws exception ?`

```
Exception :
Object of type 'System.Func`3[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Boolean]' cannot be converted to type 'Lab2.SortingMethods.HeapSort+ComparatorDelegate'.
```

something like this :

```
        Type sortingMethodClass = getSelectedSortingMethod();
        MethodInfo sortMethod = sortingMethodClass.GetMethod("sort");
        Func<int, int, bool> selectedDirectionComparator = getSelectedDirection();
        int[] numbersToSort = getValidNumbers();
        Object[] parameters = new Object[] {numbersToSort,selectedDirectionComparator};
        sortMethod.Invoke(null, parameters);
        displayNumbers(numbersToSort);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 Object[] parameters = new Object[] 
   { numbersToSort, new ComparatorDelegate (selectedDirectionComparator)};
```

Comment: Exception : Object of type 'System.Object[]' cannot be converted to type 'Lab2.SortingMethods.ComparatorUtil+ComparatorDelegate'.

Comment: at sortMethod.Invoke? Can't be true. The parameters you are passing to sort method are numbersToSort and ComparatorDelegate instance. So sortMethod.Invoke takes null and object[] with int[] and new ComparatorDelegate () right.

Comment: Sorry, my bad..it works like you said! Thank you for your answer.